# If $A$ is invertible and $A$,$A^{-1}$ contains only integers, why is $\det(A^{4}) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is invertible and $A$,$A^{-1}$ contains only integers, why does $\det(A^{4}) = 1$?
I can't find a reasonable explanation for that... I tried everything. Can someone give me a direction?

Comment: "I tried everything" - please also look for duplicates, before asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\det(A^{-1}) = \left(\det(A)\right)^{-1}$.  But by any of the usual explicit determinant formulas, $\det(A)$ and $\det(A^{-1})$ are both integers (since the coefficients of both matrices are integers).  What integers are the inverses of other integers?

Comment: So it doesn't matter if it's $\det(A)^{4}$ or $\det(A)^{2}$ or any other natural & even number then... Right?

Comment: @Lisa - you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is invertible, $\det (A)$ is a unit in the underlying ring $\mathbb{Z}$, but the unit elements in $\mathbb{Z}$ are $\pm 1$. But then $1= ( \pm 1)^{4} =(\det(A))^{4} = \det (A^{4})$.

Answer (score 0):

In any commutative ring $R$, if $A$ is a square $n \times n$ matrix, we have the formula:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\adj}{adj}\adj A \cdot A =\det A\; I,$$
which shows $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det A$  is a unit in $R$.

When $R=\mathbf Z$, this means $A$  is invertible if annd only if $\det A=\pm 1$. In this case, it is not only $\det A^4$ that is equal to $1$, but
$$\det(A^2)=(\det A)^2=(\pm1)^2=1.$$

On the other hand, if $R$ is the ring of Gaussian integers  $R=\mathbf Z[\mkern1.5mu\mathrm i\mkern1.5mu]$, $A$ will be invertible if and only if $\det A\in\{1,-1,\mathrm i,-\mathrm i\}$, so that the condition becomes
$$\det A^4=1.$$